# Terminal stuck while cloning a github repo using ssh

Tags: macos, github-actions, cloning

I've tried to clone a repo using the ssh
it loads in terminal and then abruptly sticks on a certain percentage and either remains there or throws an error -

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe 173.39 MiB | 2.89 MiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I've looked here tried using compression, shallow cloning and retrieving the rest, it does the same, sticks on a certain percentage,
my internet is working fine, I tried downloading other repo (with http) they download quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the tag ["`github-actions`"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) used on this question would suggests a GitHub remote job cloning the repository in a GitHub runner on GitHub side, not on a personal `macos` workstation.

But assuming you are cloning on `macos`:

- if an SSH URL `git@github.com:...` is an issue, check first if switching to an HTTPS URL would work better: `git clone https://github.com/...`
- check if you can clone the same repository from a different network to rule out any firewall or [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) issue